# Using extern template class with STL classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I'm trying to limit certain template instantiations of std::map, std::multimap, and std::vector to only one object file in an attempt to improve compile and link times. As far as I understand, the reason that I can't simply use

```
#include <vector>
extern template class std::vector<int>;
std::vector<int> myobj;
```

is that VS10's  header contains the definitions of all the members, so they're treated as inline by the compiler, and instantiated anyways. Is my assumption correct that it would work if I were to remove all the function bodies from the  header? If so, would anybody happen to already have such a header, and be able to share it?

I've also tried listing some members like so

```
extern template std::vector<int>::vector(); // works
extern template std::vector<int>::~vector(); // no effect
```

and while the ctor is removed, the dtor is still defined according to `dumpbin`. What is the reason for that? Is it because for some reason the dtor is considered inline and the ctor is not?

Comment: The same issue still happens with the STL implementation in Visual Studio compilers including VS 2017. It is not possible to make use of the extern template with the STL classes in Visual Studio.

Comment: The templates should be implemented in the header, however, for the extern template to have any effect, the method definitions need to be moved outside of the class body (usually in the same header file, somewhere after the class' body).

Answer (score -2):

It's by standard that the STL data structures are implemented in header files, so this isn't VS10 specific. Why do you want to limit to only one object file?

There are problems splitting templates between headers and source files - you can search for that.

Comment: I'd like to improve our compile and link times.

Comment: Use a pre-compiled header and put the STL headers in there.

Comment: I think slow compile times will be caused by other factors. Do you have function bodies in header files? Do you use forward-declaration of classes?